# A basic doubt while taking square roots of variables which have ± sign before the square root sign.

Tags: roots, quadratics, radicals

Normally, we know that √x<sup>2</sup> = |x| as x is a variable here.

But if it is ± √x<sup>2</sup> , then we simply write it as ±x , because ± has specifically asked for 2 values. So on a higher level - it doesn't matter if mod is skipped. ( Correct me if I am going wrong )

Ok so the original question was .....

---

Let **−π/6 < θ < −π/12**

Suppose **α<sub>1</sub>** & **β<sub>1</sub>** are the roots equation **x<sup>2</sup> − 2x sec(θ) + 1 = 0**

and **α<sub>2</sub>** & **β<sub>2</sub>** are roots of the equation **x<sup>2</sup> + 2x tan(θ) − 1 = 0.**

If **α<sub>1</sub> > β<sub>1</sub>** & **α<sub>2</sub> > β<sub>2</sub>**, then find the value of **α<sub>1</sub>+β<sub>2</sub>**

---

On Calculating the Roots of first equation we get them as

**sec(θ) ± | tan(θ) |**

and on Calculating the Roots of second equation we get them as

**-tan(θ) ± | sec(θ) |**

The given **answer** to this question is **-2 tan(θ)**

---

Now I don't have any problem with **α<sub>2</sub> &  β<sub>2</sub>**, as one can clearly make out that **α<sub>2</sub>** is larger than **β<sub>2</sub>** as **sec(θ)** is anyhow **positive** in the **4th quadrant**

---

But I have problem with assigning **α<sub>1</sub>** & **β<sub>1</sub>** because **√tan<sup>2</sup>(θ)** is **|tan θ|** and I guess, in this specific case we can't ignore the  mod **"| |"** sign, else **α<sub>1</sub>** & **β<sub>1</sub>** will interchange

If mod sign isn't ignored, then the answer of **α<sub>1</sub>+β<sub>2</sub>** will be **0**, as

**sec(θ) + | tan(θ) | = α<sub>1</sub>  - larger root**

**sec(θ) - | tan(θ) | = β<sub>1</sub>  - smaller root**

as it is given **α<sub>1</sub> > β<sub>1</sub>**

---

and **if mod sign is ignored**- which is what is done ( possibly due to **± sign** in formula) then

**sec(θ) +  tan(θ) = β<sub>1</sub>  - smaller root**

**sec(θ) -  tan(θ) = α<sub>1</sub>  - bigger root**

as **tan(θ)** is negative in 4th quadrant
the answer of **α<sub>1</sub>+β<sub>2</sub>** comes to **-2tan(θ)** - which is given as the solution.

---

### **So what do you think is the correct solution for the question ? Or is there anything I am specifically missing here, and so the mod was discarded ?**

---

This question was also asked in JEE Advanced ( India ) in 2016.

---

Comment: You can sort them after you find them, so the matter of whether you keep the absolute value along the way or not doesn't really matter. If you like you can describe the problem as "find the sum of the larger root of the first equation and the smaller root of the second equation", and then maybe the $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ notation wouldn't confuse you. That said I would argue this particular problem is easier by keeping the absolute value because then you don't have to fuss about whether the secant and tangent are positive or negative (until the end when/if you want to simplify).

Comment: @lan , sure by that way then the answer given by them -2tan(θ) will be the correct one.

Comment: @lan, yea sorry i did get confused initially, now got it. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your section where you come up with $\alpha_1+\beta_2=0$, you have:

$\alpha_1 = \sec(\theta)+\mid\tan(\theta)\mid$ and

$\beta_1 = \sec(\theta)-\mid\tan(\theta)\mid$.

Also we then have $\alpha_2=\sec(\theta)+\mid \tan(\theta)\mid$

and $\beta_2 =-\sec(\theta)+\mid \tan(\theta)\mid$.

So $\alpha_1+\beta_2=2\mid \tan(\theta)\mid = -2\tan(\theta)$

(last equality because, as you noted, in the fourth quadrant, tangent takes on negative values).

Comment: Deleted the comment. Finally Got it !